# how to create string with "" in soap ui custom property

Tags: json, soap, groovy, soapui

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils
String charset = (('a'..'z')).join() //+ ('0'..'9')).join()
Integer length = 9
String randomStringName = RandomStringUtils.random(length, charset.toCharArray())
log.info "randomStringName: ${randomStringName}"
testRunner.testCase.`testSuite`.setPropertyValue( "EmailId", "${randomStringName}" )
```

how to create string with "" in soap ui custom property

i have a groovy script to generate the random strings, but i need the string  should be generated in "" in custom property.

Comment: do you mean like this: `"\"${randomStringName}\""`

Comment: thank you daggett, this is exactly i needed